# Need a regular expression to detect Bullet numbers in string

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to detect Bullet numbers (heading and subheading) in a string.

Example 1.

```
1. Hello
2. World
```

Example 2

```
1 Hello
2 World
```

Example 3

```
* Hello
* World
```

Example 4

```
1 Hello1
    1.1 Word1
2 Hello2
    2.1 World2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this regex (you didn't specify the language, but considering it allows for lookaheads and lookbehinds):

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))\d\.?(?:\d+)?(?=\s)|\*(?=\s)
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/6Y1X1k/3)

Explanation:

```
(
  ?:^        # If start of line
  |          # or
  (?<=\s)    # Preceded by a space
)
\d+          # Match digit(s)
\.?          # Match dot if present
(?:\d+)?     # Match digits following dot without capturing into separate group
(?=\s)       # If followed by a space
|            # or
\*(?=\s)     # Match * if followed by space
```